# Network adapter not detected in kali linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, kali-linux

Hi guys i just got a alfa AWUS036AC wireless adapter and i have been trying to get it to work with kali. the adapter is not detected by kali and i can't connect to the internet with it however i have another wifi adapter that works fine with it. The adapter came with a driver disc but when i go to open it file manager closes and all my desktop icons disappear. Next i downloaded the driver from the website but it won't install. what do i do now?

This is the error message i get when i try to install the driver for it that i downloaded from the website.

```
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.3.0-kali1-amd64/build M=/root/AWUS036AC_036EAC_ACH_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902  modules
make[1]: *'** /lib/modules/4.3.0-kali1-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:1456: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
#
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
#
```

This is what it says in 'dmesg' when i plug in the adapter.

```
[  228.181434] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  228.314242] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8812
[  228.314248] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2,  [SerialNumber=3
[  228.314251] usb 2-2: Product: 802.11n NIC
[  228.314254] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  228.314256] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 123456
```

i am using kali version 3.18.2

if you need any other information please ask

Answer (score 0):

The trick to google for hardware support is to use the vendor and product ID (also shown by `lsusb`). So googling `0bda:8812` finds it's an RTL8812au chip which is (currently) not directly supported and needs an additional driver.

Googling `0bda:8812 kali` finds [this thread](https://forums.kali.org/archive/index.php/t-26483.html) which explains how to install the additional driver manually from the git repo.

More googling finds that under Ubuntu, there's now a [DKMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support) package for it called `rtl8812au-dkms`. Kali and Ubuntu are both based on Debian, so there's a chance Kali also has a similar package (or will have it in the near future).

Manufacturers usually don't provide Linux drivers on the included driver disk.

Answer (score -3):

try to do this 
go to kali repos add software and install wireless netframework firmware then
it must start working but install the wright one for you.

Bye!

Comment: Hey thank for the answer dude but how would i "go to kali repos add software and install wireless netframework firmware". Sorry but im new to linux